# Sonar Rule: Symbol and SymbolType always unknown

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

Creating a sonar rule:

Class to check:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class SonarTestClass {

public void main() {

    ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    Lock writeLock = rwl.writeLock();
    writeLock.lock();

    StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();
    long stampedReadLock = lock.readLock();

    ReentrantLock reeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    reeLock.lock();


    ReadWriteLock rwl1 = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    Lock writeLock1 = rwl1.writeLock();
    writeLock1.lock();
    try{
        foo();
    } finally {
        writeLock1.unlock();
    }

    StampedLock stampedLock1 = new StampedLock();
    long stampedReadLock1 = stampedLock1.readLock();
    try{
        foo();
    } finally {
        stampedLock1.unlock(stampedReadLock1);
    }

    ReentrantLock reeLock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    reeLock1.lock();

    try{
        foo();
    } finally {
        reeLock1.unlock();
    }

}

private void foo() {
}
```

Rule:

```
@Rule(key = "TSS0008")
public class LocksReleasedCheck extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {

@Override
public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
    return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION);
}

@Override
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
   MethodInvocationTree mit = (MethodInvocationTree) tree;
   if(!mit.methodSelect().is((Tree.Kind.MEMBER_SELECT))) {
       return;
   }

    MemberSelectExpressionTree memberSelectExpressionTree = (MemberSelectExpressionTree) mit.methodSelect();
    ExpressionTree expression = memberSelectExpressionTree.expression();
    if(expression.is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER)) { //&& expression.symbolType().isSubtypeOf("java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock")){
        IdentifierTree identifier = memberSelectExpressionTree.identifier();
        System.out.println(identifier.symbol());
    }
  }
}
```

But expression.symbolType() and identifier.symbol() do always return unkown type/unkown symbol when testing the rule with a unit test or with gradle test.
The sysout prints: !unknownSymbol!

Is there any reason it does not return the type (ReadWriteLock, Lock,..) ?